# How to install Xenomai on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, ubuntu-16.04, xenomai

I tried to install xenomai 2.6.5 using the instructions given at http://rtt-lwr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rtpc/xenomai.html

After following the instructions given, when I reboot the machine using the new kernel, I am not able to use my keyboard or mouse.

Comment: can you please post the error message?

Comment: @PseudoAj Initially I loaded the old kernel (default one with Ubuntu) and I think that is the reason for the behaviour of "xeno-test". When I boot using the xenomai patched kernel, my Keyboard and Mouse are not working. I have edited and updated the post.